# Remove the save file dialog when exporting Excel with filesave js

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

My goal is auto generating excel files when the time comes to 12:00. But when invoke saveAs in Filesaver.min.js, it will prompt a Save File dialog, i try to debug and remove the "OpenFileWindow" but failed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwyph.png)

Another question is why there is a Click "Mouse Event" in Filesaver.min.js, which is for openning the dialog?

```
 var t=new MouseEvent("click");
    e.dispatchEvent(t)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can't do that. A user must decide for them self what to do with the download - they can choose to not have a save file dialog if they wish - the decision is **not yours**

Comment: You can't deploy files on a user's computer without his/her permission. That would be a security breach

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, you're right.      But there is a trick in the Chrome, you can trun off the "Ask where to save each file before downloading" and set a default download path, then when calling SaveAs it will download automatically.

Comment: correct, a user can do that to their own chrome ... your little website can not control configuration settings on a users website